# Is there a way to multiply columns using a case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I am creating a report that joins two tables. The problem is from one tables `#members` there may be multiple `calendar_periods` (i.e., 201903) and varying member months, 201903 with product X = .80 and 201903 with product Y = .20.

I want to take the dollars from #claims and multiply the dollars ($1,000) for 201903 against the member months and attribute them to each of the products = X = $800 and Y = $200.

However when I do the following it works for the above scenario but it pro-rating it for others when there are not two identical calendar_periods.

For example 201803 could be .80 but there is only one record, now with below calculation I am prorating my dollars by 80%.  Is there a way around this?

I tried using a.mm * b.paid as paid and identified I was prorating lines with one record

```
select a.*, a.mm * b.paid as paid
into #final_Table_use
from #member_final a 
left join #claims_final b on a.member_id = b.member_id 
                          and a.CALENDAR_PERIOD = b.CALENDAR_PERIOD
```

I am expecting that I will prorate the dollars when there are multiple calendar periods with different products and that I will not prorate those with one calendar period record

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s I am using sql-server

Comment: Unclear.   Please give sample data, and the desired result you are trying to get based on the sample data.

Comment: Essentially the multiplication works when there are duplicate calendar_periods for the same person.  However when there is only record, one calendar_period for each person I end up prorating the dollars in error.    I only want to prorate when there are multiple records per person for the same calendar_period.  I am not sure how to add sample data?